# Global string replace RegExp not removing all matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating some small add/remove/toggle/has class functions, they all work really well, until I've got multiple instances of the same class name value on a class.

Here's where I'm at so far, you'll see I have the *'g'* flag in my removeClass Regexp:

```
Element.prototype.hasClass = function (className) {
    return new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)').test(this.className);
};

Element.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
    if (!this.hasClass(className)) {
        this.className += ' ' + className;
    }
};

Element.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    if (this.hasClass(className)) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)', 'g'), '$2');
    }
};

Element.prototype.toggleClass = function (className) {
    if (this.hasClass(className)) {
        this.removeClass(className);
    } else {
        this.addClass(className);
    }
};
```

The starting HTML:

```
<p class=" james james dean james james james">Hello</p>
```

When rendered:

```
<p class=" james dean james">Hello</p>
```

Here's my working jsFiddle, if you inspect element you can see not all *james* instances have been removed. Can anyone shed light as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)
http://jsfiddle.net/8urPs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting the class string to **always** be surrounded by white-space. Once a white-space is matched it can't be matched again. So if there are two `james` classes standing next to each other and separated by one white-space, the first `james` will match and *steal* the white-space. Then the second `james` won't match.
To resolve the problem add `*` after each bracket. It stands for *zero or more of the preceding element*.

> <s>new RegExp('(\s|^)*' + className + '(\s|$)*', 'g')</s>

<s>Here's your update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8urPs/1/</s>

### Update

According to your comment about multiple white-spaces - the problem was the replacement value. In the first approach I left it unchanged - `$2`. Actually, we don't need any content in the replacement, so we can simply change it to an empty string

```
this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)*' + className + '(\\s|$)*', 'g'), '');
```

Here's the corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8urPs/2/

Comment: Works really nicely, thank you. It does add some big whitespace around the class added though, is there anyway to overcome this?

Comment: I also noticed that. I'm not sure why this is happening. I tested it on http://regexpal.com/ and everything worked fine. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Ah yes. Seems obvious doesn't it. The RegExp will do the work so we don't need to replace with the 2nd capture group. Very nice and thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with overlapping expressions. You are replacing `james`; however, in `james james`, the middle space is shared, and regexps won't match overlapping spans.

Rewrite to either use word boundaries (`\b`) instead of spaces and beg/end, or with lookahead so as not to consume that space.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the spaces between the class names can only be part of a single match. To fix this, you can replace the final capturing group with a positive lookaheaed, like so:

```
Element.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    if (this.hasClass(className)) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(?=\\s|$)', 'g'), '');
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmm it seems using '$2' at the end actually adds this to the className: class="$2$2 dean$2$2$2 deany"

Answer (score 0):

White space after className is always matched, and then cannot be matched again. Using positive lookahead assertion can help you with that:

```
this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(?=\\s|$)', 'g'), '');
```

When you start capture group with `?=` then it is trated as assertion and not matched.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/ah3Ge/